# Powershell Import-Csv error "The member X is already present"

Tags: powershell, import-csv

I'm at my wits' end and could use an assist from this community :)

I'm trying to import a csv file in to powershell using the Import-Csv module. Here is my code:

```
Import-Csv -Path "X:\SourceData\Filename.csv"
```

This returns the following error:

```
Import-Csv : The member "3140.72" is already present.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Csv -Path "X:\SourceData\Filename.csv. ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Csv], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AlreadyPresentPSMemberInfoInternalCollectionAdd,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand
```

Doing some light review of the error, the usual culprit is a duplicate column header.  I've verified that I don't have duplicate column headers so I've eliminated that as a possible root cause.

I then moved to researching the "3140.72" that the error was reporting.  The csv file has about 500 rows and on the 150th row, I see 2 columns with the value "3140.72". This is not in the 'header' and I have other rows where columns do have matching values.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you try it manually specifying the headers: `Import-Csv -Path .\path.csv -Headers "one","two",etc.`?

Comment: Did Abraham's comment solve the problem?

Comment: as AbrahamZinala pointed out, that error USUALLY means that the import is trying to assign a data element as property a name - an "element" name. that means your CSV is missing the header line OR that there is some damage in the CSV that is causing a misreading of the file. ///// so, please add the sanitized 1st 2 lines of your CSV to your Question so folks can see what is going on.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala : Thank you for the response. Yes, I've tried to add manual headers and received the same error.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks to you as well. I'll sanitize and upload a copy of the csv

Comment: Cool. Standing by!

Comment: kool! waiting [but not with bated breath] ... [*grin*]

Comment: How about adding a variable to the front of that import and see what is in the variable? 
```$Domains = Import-Csv C:\Temp\domain.csv```
```$Domains | GM ```

Comment: @AbrahamZinala; @Lee_Dailey Here is the sanitized version of my csv file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LKHuyeJlffRK9OwR2PtpHZ5a_0BSRoSW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @dcaz Thank you for responding.  I've tried the following code: `$Test = Import-Csv -Path "X:\SourceData\Filename.csv" | Get-Member` I received the same error: `Import-Csv : The member "3140.72" is already present., etc.`

Comment: I am not getting an error when importing the csv based on what you sanitized.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I don't get the error with the sanitized csv either. I'll upload another file that returns the error

Comment: The plot thickens. I'm able to import the csv successfully when I move the file from the shared drive to my desktop and rename the file. Interestingly, I made an exact copy of the csv file and moved it to my desktop and received the error upon importing. I then tried to rename the csv file on the shared drive and received the error upon import.

Comment: maybe it is some kind of right issue?

Comment: ok thank you all for looking at this. Consider this closed and answered. And Happy New Year